# C++ Saving CSV like data in bigger file

Tags: c++, csv, storage

My application requires several files. 
I do not want to distribute them as such.
Instead I compile them all into a bigger file and read the required portions from this big file at runtime.

This worked fine so far because all my data were simply ints and floats.

But now I have a CSV like text file that I would like to store in this big file as well.

I don't know a nice approach for doing that.
I was thinking about writing a line of this text file into the big file and storing its length so that I know how many chars I have to read when I "decompile" the big file at runtime when I need the CSV text.

However that seems not very elegant to me.

The data in each line of the CSV file looks like this:

```
wstring + tab + integer + tab + wstring + tab + integer
```

Alternatively I thought about saving the entire CSV file in the big file as a string, but that seems even less elegant.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to do that nicely?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The "big file", do you create it as a binary file or as a text file? You might also want to think about the format of the file, like adding "sections" (can be done in a binary file as well), where each section contain a single type of data.

Comment: adding a start and end marker and storing the csv file in between the markers. Would this help?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The section per data type idea is awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @Jack Yes, that would help. But how would I get the CSV back into my application? Should I read the CSV into a string from the big file? I don't want to deserialize it to a file.

Comment: @tmighty you should read it line by line till you encounter the end marker.

Comment: @Jack: if you use markers, you have to escape them in your data. Much simpler to store the size prior to the data.

Comment: @tmighty: have you read about *archives* ? For example, on Unix, what you describer is a **tar**. There are libraries to write into and read from a tarball.

Comment: @Matthieu great! that reminds me of structured storage on windows. Yes. it will be a nice and elegant approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the text csv file content into your big file is simply very ineffective. The biggest issues later is that reading data from the big file will be slow as it grow large.

So I suggest, instead of loading file content to the big file, you save the csv file into a folder, then save the PATH into your big file

Comment: But I need to distribute the big file. I can not distribute a path :-)

Comment: In that case, you can use the XML format for your big file. Each piece of information will be in <DataItem type="int/float/text"> ....<DataItem> tag. 
There're a lot of XML proccessing lib (ex: XmlDocument for .NET), which allow easy edit the XML data file, besides it keep your flexibility to save different type of data.